# Installing channelflow on my Mac OsX

Tags: macos, hdf5, fftw, eigen3, fink

I am trying to install the software channelflow on my Mac OsX from the instructions on this site http://channelflow.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=docs:install. The site specifies that one has to first install fftw3, eigen and hdf5 usong fink on one's system. I have successfully installed fftw3 and eigen on my system but am not able to install hdf5 using fink ('fink install hdf5' mentions that there is no package called hdf5). I installed hdf5 using the mirror on https://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/index.html. But this installed hdf5 in usr/local whereas 'fink install' installs in /sw (I think).

Now, installing channelflow gives me the following error.

```
 MDOM18208-1:build kumarsambhava$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/channelflow ~/channelflow/trunk

-- configuring channelflow version 1.5.1
-- Build type: release
-- Basic system introspection...
-- Finding packages...

-- Found FFTW 
-- FFTW_INCLUDE_DIR=/sw/include
-- FFTW_LIBRARY=/sw/lib/libfftw3.dylib
-- Adding /sw/include to include path...
-- Adding /sw/lib/libfftw3.dylib to libraries...
-- Found Eigen3
-- EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR=/sw/include/eigen3
-- Adding /sw/include/eigen3 to include path...
-- Found HDF5 
-- HDF5 was not found.
-- Adding HDF5_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND to libraries...
-- Adding /libhdf5_cpp.so to libraries...
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:129 (CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS):
  CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS Macro invoked with incorrect arguments for macro
  named: CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:135 (CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS):
  CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS Macro invoked with incorrect arguments for macro
  named: CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS


-- LIBS=/sw/lib/libfftw3.dylib;HDF5_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND;/libhdf5_cpp.so
-- INCLUDE_DIRS=

CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
HDF5_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/channelflow
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/channelflow
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/channelflow
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/channelflow
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/channelflow
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/channelflow
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/channelflow
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/channelflow
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/channelflow
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/channelflow
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/channelflow
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/examples
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/examples
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/examples
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/examples
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/examples
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/examples
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/examples
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/examples
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/examples
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/examples
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/examples
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/examples
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/examples
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/examples
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/tests
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/tests
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/tests
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/tests
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/tests
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/tests
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/tests
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/tests
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/tests
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/tests
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/tests
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/tests
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/tests
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/tests
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/tests
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/tests
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/tests
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/tests
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/tests
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/tests
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/tests
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/tests
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/data
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/data
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/data
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/data
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/data
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/data
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/data
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/data
   used as include directory in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/data
HDF5_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "chflow_static" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/channelflow
    linked by target "chflow" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/channelflow
    linked by target "symmetryop" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
    linked by target "seriesdist" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
    linked by target "pressure" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
    linked by target "poincare" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
    linked by target "seriesdist2" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
    linked by target "perturbfield" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
    linked by target "findsoln" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
    linked by target "makestokesmode" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
    linked by target "makebasis" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
    linked by target "seriesprops" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
    linked by target "L2Dist" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
    linked by target "projectseries" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
    linked by target "continuesoln" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
    linked by target "findsymmetries" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
    linked by target "couettePoincare" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
    linked by target "movieframes" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
    linked by target "arnoldi" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
    linked by target "L2IP" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
    linked by target "continuefields" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
    linked by target "fieldprops" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
    linked by target "fieldplots" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
    linked by target "field2ascii" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
    linked by target "projectfields" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
    linked by target "couette" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
    linked by target "randomfield" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
    linked by target "makeheatmode" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
    linked by target "symmetrize" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
    linked by target "diffop" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
    linked by target "interpsoln" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
    linked by target "fieldconvert" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
    linked by target "changegrid" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
    linked by target "ascii2field" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs
    linked by target "addfields" in directory /Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/trunk/programs

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/kumarsambhava/channelflow/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://apple.stackexchange.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 0):

Cmake cannot find the hdf5 libraries. To fix this have a short look at  `<your channelflow path>/trunk/CMakeList.txt`:
In line 116, 131, and 136 you find hard coded `*.so` libraries.
You can either change the suffix to `*.dylib` or create symlinks in the corresponding library paths.